# asp.net mvc5 JsonResult usage

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, ajax.beginform

I was working on a project and I wondered how to handle json result as an object.
I succeed using a partial view as a result but I just wonder that Is that possible if I return a json result as a List.

My expected result is like that:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddMission", "Mission", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "ajaxEtki", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter }   new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }){
// Do some staff
}
```

And In the controller part

```
public JsonResult ()
{
     List<Missions> missions = _db.Missions.ToList();
     return Json(missions,JsonBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I just wonder how to handle the result in View Part(I want to use the result like objects.)

// The part I wonder is usage of that script part.
//Because I didnot succeed in that script part.
Can someone help me about how to convert that jsonresult to object list?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var obj = response.get
            alert(response);
            var isss = JSON.parse(response);

                var target = $("#ajaxEtki");
                target.empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    var product = response[i];
                    alert(product);
                    target.append(product.GOREVTURADI + "<br />");
                }
            }
            function OnFailure(response) {
                alert("false")
            }
        </script>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick sample.

1. Add unobtrusive-Ajax to you project using command `Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` in Package Manager Console.
2. Example codes as below:

**Model**

```
public class Mission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    private readonly List<Mission> _missions = new List<Mission>()
    {
        new Mission(){Name = "qw",Id = 1},
        new Mission(){Name = "er",Id = 2},
        new Mission(){Name = "ty",Id = 3}
    };
    public ActionResult Mission()
    {
        return Json(_missions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View**

```
    </div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Mission", new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "submitMissionSuccess" }))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Ok"/>
    }
```

**Scripts in view**

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        function submitMissionSuccess(response) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                $('#jsonTarget').append("<p>" + response[i].Name + "</p>");
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```